# How to express in plain English for instance that "the first N slots are filled, with N between 0 and the number of slots"

Tags: expression-choice

I'll use an abstract example: Imagine 10 slots that can each either be filled or empty. I want to communicate the information that the configuration of filled/empty slots is such that the first N slots are filled, with N between 0 and 10, e.g. slots 1, 2 are filled, the rest are empty, or slots 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are filled, the rest are empty, etc. How can I say this succinctly in plain English?

Here are some attempts:

- The first few slots are filled (bad: they're not necessarily few)
- The first N slots are filled, with N between 0 and the number of slots (too algebraic)
- The slots are filled from the beginning and on (the best I've come up with, but it alludes to the process of filling the slots, which I don't want to need to do)

Comment: An initial segment of the slots are filled.

Comment: ... You've collectivised _segment_, you bounder.

Comment: None, some, or all of the slots are filled in numerical order.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the slots are filled from left to right, or in numerical order, or something like that?

Comment: By using the concept of "slots" you introduce the false notion that each can independently be filled or empty, thus your problem. The slot is an implementation detail here.  So don't discuss them.

Comment: In an informal but technical discussion I might say "the first n < N," or (out loud) "k less than N."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that some number of slots are filled but that number *could* be any number between 0 and ALL means, simply, "Any number of slots could be filled. Or not."

The only real restriction you are placing on the description is that any slots that *are* filled are filled "front to back" or "first to last".

As far as "plain English", one phrase that will help is "so many". This simply means "an unknown number":

> 1. The first so many slots are filled. (PROBLEM: Heavily implies at least one.)
> 2. Slots should be filled first to last. (PROBLEM: Only notes the criteria.)
> 3. If slots are filled, they are the first so many slots. (Satisfies your criteria by specifically noting that none could be filled.)
> 4. Any slots filled are filled front to back. (Satisfies your criteria as this implies some number *could* be filled and it describes the condition.)

I think (4) is the easiest to understand and the most English-y but (3) is technically most similar to your given criteria.

You could also use "first to last" in (4) if that is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

The first three of ten slots are filled.

Comment: It's not necessarily three, though. It is the first N, where N can be any value between 0 and the number of slots.

Answer (score 1):

> The first couple of slots are already filled

**A couple of** is an [idiom](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/couple) meaning *more than two, but not many, of; a small number of; a few: It will take a couple of days for the package to get there.*

By placing the word, *first*, it's clear the order in which the slots are filled.

Alternatively you could say:

- **Several** of the initial slots are...
- Starting from slot No1 **a few** are...

Answer (score 1):

"A certain number of contiguous slots are filed beginning with the first slot, slot 0."